# Can't set headers after they are sent error while trying to maintain user session for a test with chai request agent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, chai

We are currently struggling with a `Uncaught Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` error message when trying to chain a user sign in into a test with chai-http.

The test signs in as a user which already exists in the database via our API and then should attempts to GET all items from an existing route. Our current test is below which mirrors very closely the example given on the Chai-HTTP documentation http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/#retaining-cookies-with-each-request.

```
it('should return all notes on /api/notes GET', function (done) {
agent
  .post('/users/register')
  .send(user)
  .then(function() {
    return agent
      .get('/api/notes')
      .end(function (err, res) {
        // expectations
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Our stack trace

```
 Uncaught Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
  at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
  at ServerResponse.header (node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
  at ServerResponse.send (node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
  at ServerResponse.json (node_modules/express/lib/response.js:249:15)
  at app/routes/usersRouter.js:16:29
  at node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:236:29
  at node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:51:48
  at pass (node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:287:14)
  at Authenticator.serializeUser (node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:289:5)
  at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:50:29)
  at Strategy.strategy.success (node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:235:13)
  at verified (node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:83:10)
  at InternalFieldObject.ondone (node_modules/passport-local-mongoose/lib/passport-local-mongoose.js:149:24)
```

This is the function being called on our users router which seems to be raising the error (not raised manually, just raised when using chai)

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
User.register(new User({ username : req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).json({info: err});
    }

    passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
        res.status(200).json({info: "success"});
    });
});
});
```

Manually testing this functionality works correctly, the issue seems to purely be down to our test and how it is interacting with passport.

Does anyone have any suggestions or pointers which could be of help?

Comment: Did you try adding a `return;` immediately after `res.status(500).json({info: err});` ? Which line is line 16 in your `usersRouter.js`?

Comment: Line 16 now, after your suggested change reads : `return res.json({'ERROR': err});`, however is still returning the same error.

Comment: Why do you use end instead of then ? In your example you mix promises with classic callbacks, maybe you should try changing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an err object being passed in the User.register callback? If so, try putting `return res.status(500).json({info: err});` so that the passport code will not run. The `return` will exit the function and will not attempt to set the headers twice.

Answer (score 0):

This all comes back to two different pieces of code both answering the request (res.send or res.json).

Essentially there are two possibilities:
1. Passport is using the res object to answer the request, before you do. Check the docs on how this should be done. 
2. You get an error and since you have a bug with a missing return in the error handler the res object is set twice.

Answer (score -2):

This is a late answer but I was just having this exact problem.

Did you try putting your passport.authenticate function inside an else statement?

I found that fixed this problem for me.

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)